# Menu scroll to X px before div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I don't really know how to explain what I mean but bear with me.
So, I got this script to get my menu to scroll to divs on my one page website:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

And it works perfectly BUT because I have a fixed menu on top, I get 50px of the target div covered by the menu itself.

I'd like to know if there's any way I can make it to scroll to 50px before the target.

I'm 0 at jquery, I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like...

```
(target.offset().top - 50)
```

Comment: That's exaclty what I meant.